# Chromedriver failing to launch Chrome properly via system account under Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

I use Jenkins to run browser automation via Chrome and chromedriver.exe. This is on a Windows Server 2008 box. My tests suddenly started failing. I can see via the console output of the running test that chromedriver is being called, and I can see via interactive desktop that Chrome has been launched. But then Chrome simply hangs and the site never loads. Jenkins is running under the local system account. If I run exactly the same tests via command line under my administrator account everything works fine.

I additionally tried installing the Chromedriver plugin for Jenkins. I can see that Jenkins downloaded a slightly newer version of chromedriver.exe and is calling it from that new location. Exact same problem persists.

Chromedriver is invoked via ruby code. I use the watir gem for browser automation. I managed to hack the ruby gem code and turn on verbose logging for Chromedriver. There is nothing alarming coming out of the chromedriver log output.

My test framework is dead in the water. Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: It seems pretty clear from reading I've done on Google's Chromedriver forums that Chrome probably auto-updated itself (which is why everything broke suddenly) and the new version of Chrome does not place nice with Chromedriver when run as a service. Lots of people's test frameworks are now broken. Solutions offered are to install a previous version of Chrome. That is problematic however because Google does not officially make older versions available, so you have dig for one somewhere on line. And, I must have a version that installs for all users instead of just for the current user.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a previous version of Chrome (v37) which I installed on my Jenkins server. However, the older installer would not install Chrome for ALL users, so I had run my Jenkins service under the administrator account I was logged in as when I installed the older Chrome version. Only then was Chromedriver able to locate chrome.exe; and then my browser automation tests worked again.